# SQL error: Msg 8120. Why Any column in your select statement that is not in the aggregate function must be in the GROUP BY clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server

SELECT OrderID,
count(ProductID),
(unitPrice * Quantity) as 'Product Total Amount',
Discount,
(unitPrice * Quantity * (1-Discount)) as 'Product Total Amount with a discount'
from [Order Details]

Comment: Please post the complete error message - and I believe it tells you exactly what is wrong

Comment: And please ask a question in the question, not just the title

Comment: The message will literally spell out what the problem is: `Column 'ProductID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.` See [Aleksandar Vasilevski's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73515045/215042) or the many duplicate questions. Next time, use the search first.

Comment: study aggregate functions

Answer (score 0):

Any column in your select statement that is not in the aggregate function must be in the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Plenty of duplicates of this question - please don't answer it again